# Loading JavaScript files via WildFly

Tags: javascript, java, wildfly-11

**I have a problem loading javascript files to my JSP page.
In opposite the css files is loading normally.**

On my *.jsp file I load scripts in the "header" section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/resources.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

In the Top of this index.jsp file I specified the character set:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

And also in the head section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

The error which is returned by WildFly (11-th version) is:

```
Exception handling request to /trust/js/resources.js: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null charset name
```

Where "/trust/js/resources.js" is my own js file, which I trying to load.

**This error arises on every *.js file**

The full error stack:
15:24:32,670 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-55) UT005023: Exception handling request to /trust/js/resources.js:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null charset name
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(Charset.java:467)
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:538)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.BlockingWriterSenderImpl.<init>(BlockingWriterSenderImpl.java:66)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletBlockingHttpExchange.getSender(ServletBlockingHttpExchange.java:76)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.getResponseSender(HttpServerExchange.java:1316)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet.serveFileBlocking(DefaultServlet.java:345)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:185)
    at javax.servlet.api//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.api//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at deployment.trust-3.1.46.war//eu.dovira.servlet.filter.ServletAccessLogger.doFilter(ServletAccessLogger.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.trust-3.1.46.war//eu.dovira.servlet.filter.NocacheFilter.doFilter(NocacheFilter.java:54)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.trust-3.1.46.war//eu.dovira.servlet.filter.TreeHtmlFilter.doFilter(TreeHtmlFilter.java:50)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.trust-3.1.46.war//eu.dovira.servlet.filter.RequestEncodingFixer.doFilter(RequestEncodingFixer.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.trust-3.1.46.war//eu.dovira.servlet.filter.RouterFilter.doFilter(RouterFilter.java:54)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.trust-3.1.46.war//eu.dovira.servlet.filter.SetHttpHeadersFilter.doFilter(SetHttpHeadersFilter.java:118)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
    at io.undertow.core//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

The firefox browser returns error by every js file (in its developers kits) see on the image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzfYV.png)

Thanks for all answers in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the servlet which is responsible to filter paths .

```
public static boolean isResourceRequest(String path){
    // Images & CSS & JS
    if(path.toLowerCase().contains("/img/") || path.contains("/css/") || path.contains("/js/") || path.contains("/upload/") || path.contains("/fonts/")){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I just changed condition by adding needed file type
There is a feature in the software architect.